# Strange behavior from a simple C program

Tags: c, arrays, pre-increment

If I run the following code, `graph[0][0]` gets `1` while `graph[0][1]` gets `4`.

In other words, the line `graph[0][++graph[0][0]] = 4;` puts `1` into `graph[0][0]` and `4` into `graph[0][1]`.

I would really appreciate if anyone can offer reasonable explanation.

I observed this from Visual C++ 2015 as well as an Android C compiler (CppDriod).

```
static int graph[10][10];
void main(void)
{
    graph[0][++graph[0][0]] = 4;
}
```

Comment: Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and avoid writing such unreadable code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sir is this really UB? Isn't it like we're operating on different elements?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This one looks well-defined, because it uses pre-increment. Had it been `graph[0][graph[0][0]++] = 4`, it would be a UB. Similarly, storing `-1` in `graph[0][0]` would cause UB with pre-increment.

Comment: But it is still extremely cryptic.

Comment: It is unreadable. And a small change makes that UB. See comment by sasblinkenlight.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Agree full-heartedly with this comment. :-)

Comment: It's just rubbish, UB or not.  It's another example of code that would get you fired immediate in industry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
++graph[0][0]
```

This pre-increments the value at `graph[0][0]`, which means that now `graph[0][0] = 1`, and then the value of the expression is `1` (because that is the final value of `graph[0][0]`).

Then,

```
graph[0][/*previous expression = 1*/] = 4;
```

So basically, `graph[0][1] = 4;`

That's it! Now `graph[0][0] = 1` and `graph[0][1] = 4`.

Comment: @AnT Could you explain that? What do you mean by `imposing an ordering where no ordering exists`? This isn't undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jashaszun: No, this isn't undefined behavior. But your claim that "now `graph[0][0] = 1`" is misleading. Evaluation of `++graph[0][0]` in the context of the original expression is not required to *modify* `graph[0][0]` immediately. All this `++` does is produce the value `1` and send it up the evaluation chain, but you cannot claim that "now `graph[0][0] = 1`". It is quite possible that `graph[0][0]` remains `0` for a while. It will become `1` much later (before the end of the full statement). C language gives you no guarantees as to when exactly it will happen.

Comment: Side-effects in this expression are not sequenced. No one knows when exactly they happen. All one can claim is that `1` will get into `graph[0][0]` and `4` will get into `graph[0][1]` sometime before the end of the full statement. Misguided belief that `++` modifies its operand *immediately* is exactly the reason that spawns confused questions of this nature here on SO and everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

First let's see what is the unary (prefix) increment operator does.

> The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented. The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation.

So, in case of

```
graph[0][++graph[0][0]] = 4;
```

first, the value of `graph[0][0]` is incremented by 1, and then the value is used in indexing.

Now, `graph` being a static global variable, due to implicit initialization, all the members in the array are initialized to `0` by default. So, `++graph[0][0]` increments the value of `graph[0][0]` to 1 and returns the value of `1`.

Then, the simpllified version of the instrucion looks like

```
graph[0][1] = 4;
```

Thus, you get

- `graph[0][0]` as 1
- `graph[0][1]` as 4.

Also, FWIW, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: That's wrong. Where did that "first" in "... first, the value of `graph[0][0]` is incremented by 1..." come from? There' no sequencing in this expression, for which reason nobody can say when the value of  `graph[0][0]` gets incremented.

Comment: @AnT sir, is not it like the array subscript operation will take higher priority? I mean, the expression in the array subscript will be evaluated first. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right: the expression in the array subscript will be evaluated first. And it will produce `1` as it result. But that has nothing to do with actually writing that `1` back into `graph[0][0]`. The modification of `graph[0][0]` is not a part of "evaluation of expression in the array subscript". It is a side-effect. That side-effect is allowed to materialize much later.

Comment: Operator *priority* has nothing to do with order of evaluation and has nothing to do with materialization of side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding one to `graph[0][0]`, by doing `++graph[0][0]`.  And then setting `graph[0][1]` to `4`. Maybe you want to do `graph[0][graph[0][0]+1] = 4`

Answer (score 1):

At first your variable  `graph[10][10]` is static so it will be initialized with value `0`.

Then line `graph[0][++graph[0][0]] = 4 ;`  here **graph[0][0] = 0**  in expression you just incrementing the value of **graph[0][0]**  so basically you assigning `graph[0][1] = 4;` yourself

**Note that you have used pre-increment operator (++x) so it first get incremented and value is changed but if you would have use post-increment operator(x++) then `graph[0][0] = 4;`  itself**

Answer (score 0):

Let's line up the facts about this expression

```
graph[0][++graph[0][0]] = 4;
```

- Per 6.5.1, the computation of the array index `++graph[0][0]` is sequenced before the computation of array element  `graph[0][++graph[0][0]]`, which in turn is sequenced before the computation of the entire assignment operator.
- The value of `++graph[0][0]` is required to be `1`. Note that this does not mean that the whole pre-increment together with its side-effects has to "happen first". It simply means that the result of that pre-increment (which is `1`) has to be computed first. The actual modification of `graph[0][0]` (i.e. changing of `graph[0][0]` from `0` to `1`) might happen much much later. Nobody knows when it will happen exactly (sometime before the end of the statement).
- This means that the element being modified by the assignment operator is `graph[0][1]`. This is where that `4` should go to. Assignment of `4` to `graph[0][1]` is also a side-effect of `=` operator, which will happen sometime before the end of the statement.

Note, that in this case we could conclusively establish that `++` modifies `graph[0][0]`, while `=` modifies `graph[0][1]`. We have two unsequenced side-effects (which is dangerous), but they act on two different objects (which makes them safe). This is exactly what saves us from undefined behavior in this case.

However, this is dependent on the initial value of `graph` array. If you try this

```
graph[0][0] = -1;
graph[0][++graph[0][0]] = 4;
```

the behavior will immediately become undefined, even though the expression itself looks the same. In this case the side-effect of `++` and the side-effect of `=` are applied to the same array element `graph[0][0]`. The side-effects are not sequenced with relation to each other, which means that the behavior is undefined.